# Update XML node based on child node values

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, nodes

I am trying to update the value of an XML tag based on the sibling nodes.

My XML looks like:

```
<root>
 <mydata>

  <submission>
   <uname>rosy</uname>
   <idlist>22,23,89</idlist>
   <status>unavailable</status>
   <oldstatus>unavailable</oldstatus>
   </submission>

   <submission>
   <uname>amy</uname>
   <idlist>22,23,89</idlist>
   <status>unavailable</status>
   <oldstatus>unavailable</oldstatus>
   </submission>

   <submission>
   <uname>rosy</uname>
   <idlist>66</idlist>
   <status>unavailable</status>
   <oldstatus>unavailable</oldstatus>
  </submission>

 </mydata>
</root>
```

I have the query that I can use to update node based on one parameter.

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
         SET MY_DATA =
                UPDATEXML (
                   MY_DATA ,
                      '/root/mydata/submission[idlist=''22,23,89'']/status/text()',
                   'paid', 
                      '/root/mydata/submission[idlist=''22,23,89'']/oldstatus/text()',
                   SYSDATE
                   )
       WHERE ROW_ID = 1234;
```

That is, currently I can look for nodes either based on "uname" or "idlist".  But I am unable to see how I could update based on two parameters together.

That is "Update status to approved where uname is rosy and idlist is 22,23,89".

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked of me is :

SET MY_DATA = 
UPDATEXML ( MY_DATA ,
'/root/mydata/submission[idlist=''22,23,89'' and uname=''rosy'']/status/text()',
'paid')

For some reason the query doesn't work when there are special characters in uname but if the field has only alphabets or numbers then it works fine.